# AucTeX issue with BVerbatim in newenvironment

Tags: verbatim, auctex, syntax-highlighting

I have the following `newenvironment` command:

```
\newenvironment{code}
{ \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{mdframed}[
    backgroundcolor=black!70,
    leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1,
    innerleftmargin=4, innertopmargin=4, innerbottommargin=4,
    leftline=false, topline=false, rightline=false,·bottomline=false
  ]\color{white}\footnotesize\begin{BVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}] }
{ \end{BVerbatim} \end{mdframed} }
```

After this, the syntax coloration in my emacs is completely broken, everything is as if I was in a `verbatim` environment (yellowish color). The only way to "fix" the coloration is by doing:

```
\end{ BVerbatim}
```

...but obviously this makes the code not compilable.

Is there a way to fix this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AUCTeX's syntax highlighting system expects the `\begin{verbatim-env-name}` in a line of its own.  You can fix your issue easily by slightly rearranging your code:

```
\newenvironment{code}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{mdframed}[
    backgroundcolor   = black!70 ,
    leftmargin        = 1        ,
    rightmargin       = 1        ,
    innerleftmargin   = 4        ,
    innertopmargin    = 4        ,
    innerbottommargin = 4        ,
    leftline          = false    ,
    topline           = false    ,
    rightline         = false    ,
    bottomline        = false ]
    \color{white}
%%% Relevant rearrangement here:
\begin{BVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
  }{
\end{BVerbatim}%
  \end{mdframed}%
}
```

It looks like this for me:

[image]

Note the color of `}{`.

As a note, I think you're better off if you use the facilities described in the manual of `fancyvrb` and `mdframed`.  Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{BVerbatim}{%
  commandchars = \\\{\}        ,
  formatcom    = \color{white} ,
  fontsize     = \footnotesize ,
}

\usepackage{mdframed,xcolor}
\surroundwithmdframed[%
backgroundcolor   = black!70 ,
leftmargin        = 1        ,
rightmargin       = 1        ,
innerleftmargin   = 4        ,
innertopmargin    = 4        ,
innerbottommargin = 4        ,
leftline          = false    ,
topline           = false    ,
rightline         = false    ,
bottomline        = false
]{code}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
{\color{cyan}\textbackslash{}surroundwithmdframed[%}
backgroundcolor   = black!70 ,
\textcolor{red}{leftmargin        = 1        ,}
bottomline        = false
\fcolorbox{green}{black}{]{code}}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

AUCTeX is able to parse this version and updates its internal variables in order to be aware of this new verbatim environment.

Comment: Re-arranging the environment did fix the issue. I tried the version with `DefineVerbatimEnvironment` but I faced two issues: 1) I don't know how to set the font size to `footnotesize` in this case (I forgot to put this in my MCVE), 2) the `\textcolor{}` commands I use inside the `code` environment do not work anymore due to the `formatcom` parameter.

Comment: @Holt - See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\newenvironment{code}
{ \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{mdframed}[
    backgroundcolor=black!70,
    leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1,
    innerleftmargin=4, innertopmargin=4, innerbottommargin=4,
    leftline=false, topline=false, rightline=false,·bottomline=false
  ]\color{white}%
  \begin{BVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}] }
{ \end{BVerbatim}
  \end{mdframed} }
```

(I obeyed the various space tokens in OP)

Comment: ah, Arash answer was posted while I was completing mine...